# Simulate tabhost click

Tags: java, android

At the moment I am using this to call the `TabHost` activity to change tabs:

```
public void switchTab(int index){
    MintTrack ParentActivity;
    ParentActivity = (MintTrack) this.getParent();
    ParentActivity.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(3);
}
```

This works well, however, the `WebView` item in tab "3" remains unfocused, until i touch it...

I need to programatically simulate a click on tab 3 then, as clicking the tab automatically places the focus on the `webview`... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will work, but you can try requesting focus for the child at index 3.

```
 ParentActivity.getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).performClick();
```